# Ubuntu crashed after big simulation

Tags: 18.04, ram, crash, programming

I have a dual boot Ubuntu 18.04LTS and Windows 10. 
I launched a big FORTRAN simulation but not too big to automatically kill the process. I played on purpose to see until the computer made it.
Unfortunately, I had a crash of Ubuntu and it does not open anymore.
I don't know what to do at all. [image]

Comment: And what was the simulation about?

Comment: There is no problem to be seen in your screenshot.

Comment: @Jos Yes but I can't open Ubuntu,this page remains intermittently.I need to figure out how to access ubuntu again

Comment: Can you reboot in recovery mode?

Comment: The best solution will be to buy a new computer and never run "big simulations" again.

Comment: @Pilot6 Oh you big joker!

Comment: status please...

Answer (score 0):

For 18.04 or newer...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`